# Compare tow list order and return the result

Tags: python, list

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
l1 = [2,5]
l2 = [5,1]
```

```
compare(l1,l)
result = PASS
compare(l2,l)
result - FAIL
```

I have a main list called l. I need to compare the order of the list - If l1 is in the order of l then the result is "PASS", then comparing l2 is in the order of l the it is not in the order of l then "FAIL"

Comment: Hint: The position of `e` in list `mylist` is given by `mylist.index(e)`. For an order match, the positions of the candidate list elements will be in ascending order: for `l1` it will be `[1,4]` but for `l2` it will be `[4,0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def compare(tested, base):
    indexes = [base.index(t) for t in tested]
    return {True: "PASS", False: "FAIL"}[indexes == sorted(indexes)]

print(compare(l1, l))
```

Comment: `[base.index(t) for t in tested]` is a major antipattern and `{True: "PASS", False: "FAIL"}[indexes == sorted(indexes)]` is just bad style, use `if-else`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga why is this an antipattern and what pattern do you think we should use?

Comment: l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
l1 = [2, 5]
l2 = [5, 1]
l3 = [2, 3]
l4 = [3, 5]
l5 = [5, 4]


def compare(main_list, third_list):
    find = False
    while True:
        for i in third_list:
            for j in main_list:
                if i == j:
                    find = compare(main_list[main_list.index(i) + 1:], third_list[third_list.index(j) + 1:])
            if find is False:
                return False
        return True


print(compare(l, l1))
print(compare(l, l2))
print(compare(l, l3))
print(compare(l, l4))
print(compare(l, l5))

Comment: @АлексейР because it is an O(N*M) algorithm when you can do it in O( max(N, M) ). Create a map of the values to the indices then use that map